# didEnterRegion method does not call with the actual beacon device

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I am using iBeacons for the beacon connectivity and I am able to listen to all the delegate methods of Location Manager if and only if I use another iPhone as the beacon transmitter.

The same functionality I am expecting with the actual beacon hardware so I replaced another iPhone (which is acting as transmitter) with the beacon hardware. This results in didDetermineState method call back with the value of CLRegionState parameter as CLRegionStateUnknown and then as CLRegionStateOutside.

I have noticed the value of the same parameter as CLRegionStateInside when using iPhone device as the beacon transmitter.

I am wondering how come the same code works with the iPhone device as the transmitter whereas it fails with no result with the actual beacon device.

Can anyone help me out to understand and resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your beacon is not working properly.  I would test the beacon with an off the shelf beacon app like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8).  (If using this app, be sure to configure your beacon UUID into the app so it can be detected.). If you cannot detect it, get another beacon.